# Configure Search for a specific Column

Tags: search, search-results, managed-metadata, query

I'm creating kind of a knowledge base in SharePoint. I have a list with columns Title, Issue, Solution and Topics. Topics rely on managed metadata from termstore.

When People use the search of the site or of the list, the only column searched in should be `Topics`.

I already tried to help me with query tranform in a new Default result source:

```
Topics: {searchboxquery} AND PATH:https://***/Lists/Knowledgelist*
```

With this transform, SharePoint will still do a full text search on the whole table. Is there any OOTB solution or even a better solution for a efficient search?

Answer (score 1):

Before you can filter on this column, you must create managed property mapped to crawled property in search schema, set it as Queryable and reindex content.

[More info](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667(v=office.16).aspx)

Comment: Thanks you! Well i created a managed property and when i mapped there was already "Topic" available. I set The Property on queryable. But now I can't work out how to connect the property with my search or my list.

Comment: Just modify Query Transform for default Result Source to something like this: `{?Topics:{searchTerms} Path:https://contoso/Lists/Knowledgelist}`.