# How do I create a search query by column name in Manage Result Sources?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, query, result-source

I have a document library. And I wrote a query in the search that brought only the documents in this list. But in addition, I want a column-bound search in this list.

****There is a document library as shown in this example.**

**In the searches on the page, I only provide the fetching of these documents with a query.**

**However, I would like to search by column C for example.****

How can i do this?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Try [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208805/configure-search-for-a-specific-column) if it is useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the search schema, you need to create a managed property, then map the crawled property column C to this managed property.

After a full crawl, you could use `<managed property>:<Property Value>` in your query.

Comment: yes it works !! thanks.